# Fourier transform floating point issues

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, fft

I am implementing a conventional (that means *not* fast), separated Fourier transform for images. I know that in floating point a sum over one period of sin or cos in equally spaced samples is *not* perfectly zero, and that this is more a problem with the conventional transform than with the fast.

The algorithm works with 2D double arrays and is correct. The inverse is done inside (over a double sign flag and conditional check when using the asymmetric formula), not outside with conjugations. Results are nearly 100% like expected, so its a question about details:

When I perform a forward transform, save logarithmed magnitude and angle to images, reload them, and do an inverse transform, I experience different types of rounding errors with different types of implemented formulas:

1. F(u,v) = Sum(x=0->M-1) Sum(y=0->N-1) f(x,y) * e^(-i*2*pi*u*x/M) * e^(-i*2*pi*v*y/N)

   f(x,y) = 1/M*N * (like above)
2. F(u,v) = 1/sqrt(M*N) * (like above)

   f(x,y) = 1/sqrt(M*N) * (like above)

So the first one is the asymmetric transform pair, the second one the symmetric. With the asymmetric pair, the rounding errors are more in the bright spots of the image (some pixel are rounded slightly outside value range (e.g. 256)). With the symmetric pair, the errors are more in the constant mid-range area of the image (*no* exceeding of value range!). In total, it seems that the symmetric pair produces a bit more rounding errors.

Then, it also depends of the input: when image stored in [0,255] the rounding errors are other than when in [0,1].

So my question: how should an optimal, most accurate algorithm be implemented (theoretically, no code): asymmetric/symmetric pair? value range of input in [0,255] or [0,1]? How linearly upscaling result before saving logarithmed one to file?

**Edit**:

my algorithm simply computes the separated asymmetric or symmetric DFT formula. Factors are decomposed into real and imaginary part using Eulers identity, then expanded and sumed up separately as real and imaginary part:

```
sum_re += f_re * cos(-mode*pi*((2.0*v*y)/N)) - // mode = 1 for forward, -1
          f_im * sin(-mode*pi*((2.0*v*y)/N));  // for inverse transform
// sum_im permutated in the known way and + instead of -
```

This value grouping indside cos and sin should give in my eyes the lowest rounding error (compared to e.g. `cos(-mode*2*pi*v*y/N)`), because not multiplicating/dividing significantly false rounded transcedental pi several times, but only one time. Isn't it?

The scale factor `1/M*N` or `1/sqrt(M*N)` is applied separately after each separation *outside* of the innermost sum. Better inside? Or combined completely at the end of both separations?

For some deeper analysis, I have quitted the `input->transform->save-to-file->read-from-file->transform^-1->output` workflow and chosen to compare directly in double-precision: `input->transform->transform^-1->output`.

Here the results for an real life 704x528 8-bit image (delta = max absolute difference between real part of input and output):

- with input inside [0,1] and asymmetric formula: delta = 2.6609e-13 (corresponds to 6.785295e-11 for [0,255] range).
- with input insde [0,1] and symmetric formula: delta = 2.65232e-13 (corresponds to 6.763416e-11 for [0,255] range).
- with input inside [0,255] and asymmetric formula: delta = 6.74731e-11.
- with input inside [0,255] and symmetric formula: delta = 6.7871e-11.

These are no real significant differences, however, the full ranged input with the asymmetric transform performs best. I think the values may get worse with 16-bit input.

But in general I see, that my experienced issues are more because of scaling-before-saving-to-file (or inverse) rounding errors, than real transformation rounding errors.

However, I am curious: what is the most used implementation of the Fourier transform: the symmetric or asymmetric? Which value range is in general used for the input: [0,1] or [0,255]? And usual shown spectra in log scale: e.g. [0,M*N] after asymmetric transform of [0,1] input is directly log-scaled to [0,255] or before linearly scaled to [0,255*M*N]?

Comment: If you are using the same core algorithm and are just scaling the results differently, the differences in errors should be incidental, essentially just random chance about how the roundings happen to occur. We would need details of what you are doing to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors you report are tiny, normal, and generally can be ignored. Simply scale your results and clamp any results outside the target interval to the endpoints.

In library implementations of FFTs (that is, FFT routines written to be used generally by diverse applications, not custom designed for a single application), little regard is given to scaling; the routine often simply returns data that has been naturally scaled by the arithmetic, with no additional multiplication operations used to adjust the scale. This is because the scale is often either irrelevant for the application (e.g., finding the frequencies with the largest energies works no matter what the scale is) or that the scale may be distributed through multiply operations and performed just once (e.g., instead of scaling in a forward transform and in an inverse transform, the application can get the same effect by explicitly scaling just once). So, since scaling is often not needed, there is no point in including it in a library routine.

The target interval that data are scaled to depends on the application.

Regarding the question on what transform to use (logarithmic or linear) for showing spectra, I cannot advise; I do not work with visualizing spectra.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling causes roundoff errors. Hence, solution 1 (which scales once) is better than solution 2 (which does it twice). Similarly, scaling once after summation is better than scaling everything before summation.

Do you run `y` from `0` to `2*N` or from `-N` to `+N` ? Mathematically it's the same, but you have an extra bit of precision in the latter case.

BTW, what's `mode` doing in `cos(-mode * stuff)` ?

Comment: y runs from 0 to N (not 2*N). Yes, indeed, I could run only from 0 to N/2 (if N even, else floor(N/2) with extra handling of ceil(N/2)), and not *compute* but just conjugate the remaining y. Maybe this will be more precise, I'll check it. `mode` is the mode of the transform: if 1 then forward, if -1 then inverse (the formulas of forward and inverse transform differ (except the factor of the asymmetric case) only by that sign).

Comment: And with the scaling inside sum: I could imagine, that maybe even if there are absolutely more rounding errors, they compensate since sin/cos fluctuates from -1 to 1.

Comment: @mb84: It's non-trivial mathematics, but I believe that the rounding errors won't cancel here. Basically, they're uncorrelated to each other, but each is correlated to the magnitude of their individual term. Since those terms themselves cancel, the sum is relatively small compared to the individual terms (except for DC, v=0 of course). That means you're adding a fairly large number of fairly large errors. While the _expected_ error of that will be 0, the _standard deviation_ will be something like `O(sqrt(N))` larger.

Comment: @mb84: The mode comment was mathematical: `cos` is even so `cos(-mode*stuff)` is just `cos(stuff)`. Then again, your compiler might be smart enough to use a fused sincos function where appropriate.

Comment: ah ok, now I understand your comment on `mode`. I like it as written because of readability. And I noticed that I cannot use the `F(u,v)==conjugate(F(-u,-v))` property, because I want to allow whole complex input. About roundig errors I will multiplicate with constants as rare as possible. Compared to [0,255] the errors are really insignificant. It remains the log-scaling of the spectrum, in which I am interested: how is it done in general (see my very last question in my first post)?